# ServerSentEvent Connection Issue when Multiple Clients Access the application concurrently

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I want to implement an event based client server communication. Whenever some response comes in backend(Spring boot java) as part of some post operation(for eg:-payment process), need to post that backend data to frontend(Angularjs) which is specific to each user. Each user should get his specific response in browser. Multiple clients can concurrently access the application for the payment operation.

Our plan is to implement this using ServerSentEvent, as this is one way communication.

Doing one POC with angularjs as frontend and springboot as backend. I am creating multiple event sources by creating separate instances for each user request like this:-
const eventSource = new EventSource(`http://localhost:8082/api/chat/sse/${clientId}`);

clientId is used to differentiate users.

Test scenario:-
User 1 performed his payment operation from browser1(chrome). EventSource http://localhost:8082/api/chat/sse/1 gets created for user1.

User 2 performed his payment operation from browser2(edge) simultaneously. EventSource http://localhost:8082/api/chat/sse/2 gets created for user2.

User 1 registered EventSource first and user 2 registered last.
When I try to create multiple eventsources for different users, now what is happening is only the last created eventsource(here user 2) is going to open state and getting response back.
Rest of the user's EventSource are not going to open state and from backend it's showing error like client aborted connection.

So here my query is:-

Is ServerSentEvent not applicable for this scenario ?
Does ServerSentEvent not support concurrent multiple user connections at a time?
Is this browser specific limitation ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.